# Pause and continue Wi-Fi sniffing in Terminal using airport command

Tags: terminal, wifi, airport

I'm capturing packets on a specific channel using "airport" command on Mac OS X Sierra. The command saves the packets into a *.cap file in my tmp folder. The file is already almost 2 GB large.
What I would like to do is to pause the capturing process and then be able to continue to capture on the same channel and into the same *.cap file.
I'm afraid to just abort the command in Terminal using CTRL+C because then after rerunning the command I suspect it will just create another *.cap file and not continuing using the original one.

The exact command I ran is:

```
sudo airport sniff 12
```

Anyone can help please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use cat to glue the files together, i.e. cat file1.cap file2.cap file3.cap > all.cap

Comment: @JohnKeates The .cap files are binary files, and `cat` will not work properly with these. They can be merged in Wireshark, however.

Answer (score 1):

You can suspend a command in the bash shell using control-Z. To resume the command, run `fg`.

Comment: ok, that seems to be working but let's my computer suddenly restarts and I want to continue capturing on the same channel and into the same *.cap file. Is there a way in a scenario like this? Thanks

Comment: @user Can you edit your question with the exact airport command you’re running?